# Activity with webview crashing (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, webview, nullpointerexception

**Edit : SOLVED, two xml files "individual_stats.xml" were present in the project.**

After several pieces of research on the Internet, I haven't found any solution about my Activity crashing. The activity only contains a webview.

Moreover, I am new on Android Studio.

Here is the fatal error :

```
06-02 22:57:06.255 7618-7618/fr.berwick.smsstats E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   Process: fr.berwick.smsstats, PID: 7618
                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{fr.berwick.smsstats/fr.berwick.smsstats.IndividualStats}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.webkit.WebSettings android.webkit.WebView.getSettings()' on a null object reference
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2659)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.webkit.WebSettings android.webkit.WebView.getSettings()' on a null object reference
                                                                       at fr.berwick.smsstats.IndividualStats.onCreate(IndividualStats.java:19)
                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6672)
                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1140)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2612)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473) 
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123) 
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

Please consider the following : when I add the webview to the layout (dragging it), ID filed is blank, so I named the WebView "WebView" and added android:id="@+id/WebView" to my activity xml file "individual_stats.xml".

Here is the code inside the IndividualStats.java file :

```java
package fr.berwick.smsstats;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class IndividualStats extends Activity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.individual_stats);

            WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView);
            webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webview.loadUrl("https://speeload.com/");

        }
}
```

Thank you for your help, have a great day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found out what was wrong :

I got two xml files named "individual_stats.xml".
I deleted them and created a new one, it is now working.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving your webview in your xml a more unique name?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
final WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView);
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

WebSettings websetting = webview.getSettings();
websetting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.loadUrl("https://speeload.com/");
```

Comment: It seems like I get the same error, please check the error log : https://pastebin.com/bZdugaMK.

Comment: try remove :     webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

Answer (score 0):

Against which compileSdkVersion and minSdkVersion are you developing? On which API runs your device / emulator? Could be an older WebKit bug.